# How to run Selenium WebDriver java/testNG script with Windows Safari browser?

Tags: selenium, webdriver, selenium2

I know how to run test script in chrome and firefox. Please help me how to run my Selenium WebDriver java/testNG script in windows safari browser.

Answer (score 2):

Setting up Selenium tests to run on Safari browser is a fairly complex process. You need to install Safari Extensions Developer Certificate in your machine and also install selenium webdriver as an extension in Safari Browser.

Also there are some stability issues with Safari browser automation & Selenium combination on Mac 10.9 OS and below. The stability is much better on Mac Yosemite OSX & Safari 8.0.x combination along with Selenium v2.45.0

Detailed steps for the setup can be seen [here](https://itisatechiesworld.wordpress.com/selenium/selenium-webdriver/steps-to-get-safari-webdriver-running-on-mac-osx/)

Comment: **UPDATE (18th June,2015):** With the latest update of Yosemite 10.10.3 & Safari 8.0.6, the execution on Safari Browsers has become unstable & unreliable.

Selenium Scripts work best on 10.10.2 , Safari 8.0.3 & Selenium 2.45.0 combination.

So if OSX prompts you for updates, please **DO NOT** install them if you want to run automation on Safari Browser

Answer (score 1):

You need the `SafariDriver` extension for your Safari browser and you have to set two system properties:

- `webdriver.safari.driver` - Location of the Safari browser extension file
- `webdriver.safari.noinstall` - Set to `true`, if the extension already installed; else `false`.

Links:

- [SafariDriver - Selenium Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver)
- [SafariDriverInternals - Selenium Wiki](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriverInternals)